# delete array field in a mongodb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, sails.js

I am using mongoDB and my JSON (table name is "student") looks like

```
           [{
             name : "John",
             subjects:["English", "Maths"]
            },
            {
             name : "Winsel",
             subjects : ["Maths"]
            }]
```

here "subjects" is some other table and associated with student, I able to get data by using find query,

```
student.find({}).populate('subjects').then(function(studentData){console.log(studentData)})
```

by using this query i can get Data as

```
           [{
             name : "John",
             subjects:["English", "Maths"]
            },
            {
             name : "Winsel",
             subjects : ["Maths"]
            }]
```

after that i need to delete the field "subjects" which length is less than 2, I am using

```
             if(studentData.subjects.length < 2){
                 delete studentData.subjects
             }
```

but it doesn't delete the field, it shows the same result when i not using the if condition.
my expected JSON is

```
      [{
         name : "John",
         subjects:["English", "Maths"]
        },
        {
         name : "Winsel"
        }]
```

Can any one guide me, Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to delete the field in the database or only in your json response from the database ?

Comment: i want to delete the field only in JSON response not in DB

Comment: You can see my answer to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var studentsList = [{
                      name : "John",
                      subjects:["English", "Maths"]
                    },
                    {
                      name : "Winsel",
                      subjects : ["Maths"]
                   }];

var newStudentList = _.map(studentsList , function(eachStudentData){
                          if(eachStudentData.subjects <2){
                              return _.pick(eachStudentData, 'name');
                          } else {
                              return eachStudentData;
                          }
                     });
```

You can use the newly formed students list newStudentList for your code

Answer (score 1):

To remove the fields in your json response, you can use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) inside the callback function of your query function.

```
student.find({}).populate('subjects').then(function(studentData){
      var newData = studentData;

      newData.map(item => {
        if(item.subjects.length < 2) {
            delete item.subjects;
        }
        return item;
      })
      // you can use the newData here;

      })
```

Answer (score 0):

This works to me. I don't know if you are working with a JSON object and you need to transform it to javascript object  (students.toObject()).

```
var students = studentsJSON.toObject();

var newStudents = students.map(studentData => {
    if(studentData.subjects.length < 2) {
        delete studentData.subjects;
    }
    return studentData;
});
```

Comment: You are using `delete` on a JSON object. But the question is more about deleting from the database.

Comment: I am not asking to delete in DB itself, but i need to get the JSON output without array length greater than 1

Comment: Try to do .toObject to your students JSON element, I edited the example

Comment: delete studentData.subjects by using this command, it does nothing, when use this command delete studentData.subjects[0], it gives the output as [{
             name : "John",
             subjects:["English", "Maths"]
            },{name : "Winsel", subjects : []}]

Comment: I don't know what you are doing different, it works to me.

Comment: var studentData = [{
                    name: "John",
                    subjects: ["English", "Maths"]
                  },
                  {
                    name: "Winsel",
                    subjects: ["Maths"]
                  }
                ];
studentData.map(function(eachStudent){
    if(eachStudent.subject.length < 2){
        delete studentData.subjects
    }
})
when i use to delete the field name using delete eachStudent.name it delte the field, but when it is an array it doesn't do anything

Comment: What version of nodeJS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
var data = [{
    name: "John",
    subjects: ["English", "Maths"]
  },
  {
    name: "Winsel",
    subjects: ["Maths"]
  }
];
console.log(data);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].subjects.length < 2) {
    delete data[i].subjects;
  }
}
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve here but populate works on application level . you can directly use aggregation pipeline for this using $project(or similar $addFields) and $lookup

```
db.students.aggregate(

    [
        {
            $addFields: {
               subjects:{
                 $cond:[{$gte:[{$size:"$subjects"},2]},"$subjects",null]
               }
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                "from" : "subjects",
                "localField" : "subjects",
                "foreignField" : "name",
                "as" : "subjects"
            }
        },

    ]
);
```

from mongodb 3.6 you can use "$$REMOVE" instead of null in addFields stage
and also after $lookup you can use $project again to remove empty array